# IE7 padding-left line wrap problem

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a `<font>` element that is line wrapping, however `padding-left:30px;` or `margin-left:30px` only indent the first line in IE7.

Unfortunatley, as its a web-app Im unable to change the `<font>` element to something else, such as a div. Anyone have a CSS fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add display: block; to the font element

```
<style>
    font { display: block; padding-left: 30px; margin-left: 30px; }
</style>
```

Other than that, you should really push to get rid of those funky deprecated html tags. 
Remind the people in charge that this is 2011 and not 1990...

Comment: Well its actually its a built in function of struts 1.2. Should really upgrade, but timescales are always the problem.